# Disabling IRQ #32

Tags: kernel

Suddenly, out of the blue, I got this message:

```
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi
Kernel: [1277.201127] Disabling IRQ #32
```

and then my PI froze.
What could be causing this and how would I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been facing similar issues.

Getting a powered USB hub seems to solve the problem.
As when I connect the extra cable to one of the usb power, it seems to draw power and enable it again.

Edit:
I used the one in the diagram to add extra micro usb to draw power. which has VGA(my monitor) on one side and HDMI(towards raspberry) on the other, with this extra slot to add more power to display.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the IRQs. The IRQs are in /proc/irq/

`ls /proc/irq/`
(see all the IRQs?)
ok. `cd /proc/irq/32/

ls

`i have 3 folders, and a file named spurious.
as far as I can tell, every IRQ has a spurious file, which reads some thing like:`
cat spurious
count 20
unhandled 0
last_unhandled 0 ms`

Post back with what your spurious file reads, perhaps, set up some sort of watch dog, or log for the IRQ.

Can you force the condition to occur, or reproduce the results systematically?
Next, look at the interrupts, what is IRQ 32 assigned to?  Are there errors?
`cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0

  3:     410032   ARMCTRL  BCM2708 Timer Tick
 16:          0   ARMCTRL  bcm2708_fb dma
 32:   11828802   ARMCTRL  dwc_otg, dwc_otg_pcd, dwc_otg_hcd:usb1
 52:          0   ARMCTRL  BCM2708 GPIO catchall handler
 65:          7   ARMCTRL  ARM Mailbox IRQ
 66:          1   ARMCTRL  VCHIQ doorbell
 75:          1   ARMCTRL
 77:      15088   ARMCTRL  bcm2708_sdhci (dma)
 83:         20   ARMCTRL  uart-pl011
 84:      48212   ARMCTRL  mmc0
FIQ:              usb_fiq
Err:          0`

The spurious files, from what i can tell are handlers for errors, It would be ironic for it to cause errors. 
Heres a document on IRQ handling. http://os.csie.ncku.edu.tw/drupal/sites/default/files/23/13_Interrupt%20Handling.pdf
Sorry this reads more like A comment, Im not sure how to solve your problem yet, but i see many pple having this issue, so I will look into it.
My guess is, there is a module (device driver) that hangs. All we have to do is figure out what that device is.

What maybe you can set some logging on `dmesg`  and catch the error in the kernel ring buffer. Maybe then we can solve it by blacklisting a module or something.

Comment: How many USB devices are you driving with the PI Through a hub or whatever?

Comment: when the Pi hangs, is it responsive to internal commands like REISUB? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Answer (score 0):

possible answer in this thread:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=66962

Too much things connected at the same time: bluetooth dongle, usb keyboard & Ethernet... Leaving only 1 of these I don't have the problem anymore

Comment: This answer says over current is the issue, get a powered hub.